# Add WSID in EF connectionstring

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to pass a WSID in the connectionstring of an Entity Framework context.
I dont want to update all the instanciations that i have, to pass a new connectionstring so i was wondering if there is a method to override that can be of help?

For information, i have this actually:

```
using(var context = new SampleEntities())
```

and i dont want to rewrite it like that:

```
using(var context = new SampleEntities(NewConnectionString))
```

I tried to override the CreateContext method without success...

Comment: Where are you getting that new connection string from?

Comment: Don't focus on that, it's just a simple string and it's not the way i want to solve the problem.

Comment: Can you put your code in the SampleEntities ctor? It's hard for me to give you a solution track if I don't want what manipulation you have to do.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to know, SampleEntities is just the instanciation of an EntityFramework context. What i want to know is, is there a method where i can put an additional parameter to the connectionstring to identify the connected user inside my DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With EntityFramework 6, it's not more possible to pass natively a connection string to the constructor of the context (there's no more constructor for that) so i had overload my context class to add the constructor

```
public partial class MyObjectEntities : DbContext
{
    public MyObjectEntities(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
    }
}
```

In addition, because it's not possible to update the connection string inside the context after instanciation, i had to make the desired connection string before instanciating of my context.
So to do that, i created a dll project (sharable between mutiples projects) able to configure my environnement and containing my desired WSID.

Here is the construtor of a connection string gave by Microsoft http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/bb738533%28v=vs.110%29.aspx